# Only vibrate when there are no active notifications

Tags: sms, notifications, whatsapp-messenger, vibration, telegram

Is there a way to tell android only to vibrate if there are no active notifications?

Example: I use telegram messenger, and when receiving a message the phone vibrates. Even so I do not use the phone in the meantime, it will vibrate again for each incoming message. This holds also true for email notifications, SMS etc. This is very annoying when you take part in Group chats in Telegram or WhatsApp, as in a short timeframe lots of messages can arrive.

What I want: I only want the phone to vibrate ONCE. I then know "okay, there is something new that i need to look at, but I am currently busy and will do it later". Until I do not check the phone, I do not want to receive any further vibrations (the led light on my MotoG is flashing already, telling me that there are notifications).

Can this be done?

Comment: if your device is rooted and running android version 4.4 or less then you might want to look at the xposed framework. Xposed allows modules to interact deeply with the system. There is a module called `Less Frequent Notifications` in which you can limit the sound, the vibration and the time frame you'd like to receive only one notification (5 seconds to 30 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) this way:
-First, deactivate notification sounds for all apps.
-Then, configure tasker to suit your needs. [This resource might help](http://tasker.wikidot.com/sms-notification-management).
Note that root access might be required.

Comment: I've rooted in the meantime, will take a look at tasker

Comment: @Dyna great :) let me know if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

No doubt there is a solution out there, however if you're not rooted you probably can't access it.

Xposed or tasker will probably have some solution.